# Submit refresh form one input with ajax and variable id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to refresh number without page reload in the span  `<span class="badge badge-light">` after submitting a form only with the id "`formid-<?php echo $i; ?>`" where the `$i` always changes. I need the ajax code too and how to put it together. I have found something like this but couldn't make it work:

```
jQuery.on('submit', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var formID = $(this).data('i');

//call $.ajax();

}
```

and ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: $("form").attr("action"),
  data: $("form").serialize(), 
  or your custom data either as object {foo: "bar", ...} or foo=bar&...
  success: function(response) { ... },
 });
```

My form is like it:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="formid-<?php echo $i; ?>"> 
        <h6  class="badge badge-warning font top-8"><input type="submit" name="send" value="Subscribe">
   <span class="badge badge-light">

 <?php 

 echo $subscriptions; // this is the number

   ?>

   </span>
  <span class="sr-only">Subscribe</span>

</h6>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

> `jQuery.on('submit'` the handler is invalid. Even if you are using [**`event-delegation`**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), you should be using the second argument as a selector.

```js
jQuery("form[id^='form-']").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formID = $(this).data('i');
    //call $.ajax();
  }
}
```

**Note:** With event delegation, it would be `jQuery("body").on("submit", "form[id^='form-']", function(){})`

Comment: as far as I can understand this is not a whole code it doesn't work for me, I know very little in javascript, sorry )

Comment: I submit the form via php UPDATE